# UICollectionView passed in collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: is nil

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I have a collection view in a uiviewcontroller using storyboard. View controller delegate methods are called but the collectionView argument is nil on variables view. I cannot use the view for anything, I can log it on console with NSLog but not with po. For example in

`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

cv is nil on variables view. What could be the reason?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you confirming its nilness?  If this is a regular Apple `UICollectionView` and the method is being called by the collection view, there's no reason for the collection view argument to be nil.

Comment: Have you written your own collection view or downloaded someone's collection view from github? Or are you calling this method manually.

Comment: I am using standard UICollectionView, and yes, I confirmed on the console that it is nil.

Comment: While the code is within this method?  What exactly do you mean "on the console"?

Comment: yes exactly, I put a breakpoint inside this method and it is nil.

Comment: Can you show your code in this method and include a screen shot of the breakpoint and the confirmation that it is indeed `nil`?  Or just add this to the method: `NSLog(@"%p", cv);`

Comment: check the images above please, it is nil on variables view. I cannot use the view for anything, I can log it on console with NSLog but not with po.

Comment: and another weird thing is the section is 6749091040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are not in "Release" mode?

If you want to debug your application, you'll need to be in "Debug mode".

To check, go to the top left near the start button and click on your project name. Then choose "Edit Scheme". On the "Info" tab, you should have your build configuration set to "Debug", not "Release".

If you are in "Release" mode, then stopping on breakpoints won't do you any good. Everything will appear nil.